# Hello there, java/database near where syntax error

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite

Everytime i try to update it says - near "WHERE":syntax error. I have successfully been able to update other parts of the classes in the program but this somehow gives me this error.

I think the problem lies here:

```
public void update_account(){
           try { //start or try
               //1)create a connection variable
               Connection con;
               //2)create an instance of the database class
               Database db=new Database();
               //3)pass the connection from DB to con
               con=db.open_connection();
               //4)create a statement variable to prepare the SQL
               Statement statement=con.createStatement();
               //5)create a query to insert the records
               String query="UPDATE tblUsers SET fullname='" + txtFullname.getText()+"',"
                    + "username='" + txtUsername.getText()+"',"
                    + "password='" + txtPassword.getText()+"',"
                    + "WHERE userID="+ accid +"";
               //6) execute the SQL code
               if(statement.executeUpdate(query)==1) { //query was successful
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reference successfully updated!");
                   //clear the inputs
                   new MainInterface(user);
                   frmAccountSett.dispose();

               }
           }//end of try
           catch (Exception e){//start of catch
               //display the error
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
           }//end of catch
        }//end of save_recipe()
```

Here's the whole code just in case;

```
public void update_account(){
           try { //start or try
               //1)create a connection variable
               Connection con;
               //2)create an instance of the database class
               Database db=new Database();
               //3)pass the connection from DB to con
               con=db.open_connection();
               //4)create a statement variable to prepare the SQL
               Statement statement=con.createStatement();
               //5)create a query to insert the records
               String query="UPDATE tblUsers SET fullname='" + txtFullname.getText()+"',"
                    + "username='" + txtUsername.getText()+"',"
                    + "password='" + txtPassword.getText()+"',"
                    + "WHERE userID="+ accid +"";
               //6) execute the SQL code
               if(statement.executeUpdate(query)==1) { //query was successful
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reference successfully updated!");
                   //clear the inputs
                   new MainInterface(user);
                   frmAccountSett.dispose();

               }
           }//end of try
           catch (Exception e){//start of catch
               //display the error
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
           }//end of catch
        }//end of save_recipe()
```

Comment: You don't need a comma before where keyword

Comment: ahh ok! thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :) !

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` instead of concatenating a statement together, especially if the values come from user input - otherwise you're creating a [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) problem (SQL injection vulnerability).

Answer (score 1):

For sql table update, the syntax is as follows:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Notice that there is no comma before the where keyword. In your code, you are adding the comma before your WHERE keyword leading to the error

Comment: Yeap i have changed accordingly and removed the comma. Thank you!